# iOS tabBarItem badge value change from any View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Im developing an iOS app using objective c. in my app if user is not register then register view controller is `rootViewController`. if user is register then `tabBarController` having three tabs is `rootViewController`. i have to set `tabBarItem` badge value from any view controller. suppose if i am on third tab and it is having segue with another view controller and i am on that view controller, i have to change the `tabBarItem` badge value of first view controller from here.   in my case the `tabBarItem` badge value update only i go to that tab as i am using

```
NSString *upcomingcount=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)self.arrbadge.count];
            self.navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue=upcomingcount;
```

in viewwillappear.

is there any way to set the badgeValue from any `ViewController`? i want to update badge value from any `ViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz use this method in your app delegate

```
 - (void)update_badgeWithViewControllerIndex:(NSInteger)ViewControllerIndex {


            UITabBarController *tabBarController =(UITabBarController*)[[(AppDelegate*)
                                                                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];


              // Set the tab bar number badge.
              UITabBarItem *tab_bar = [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:ViewControllerIndex] tabBarItem];

              // Show the badge if the count is
              // greater than 0 otherwise hide it.

              if ([badgeValue > 0) {
                  [tab_bar setBadgeValue:badgeValue]; // set your badge value
              }

              else {
                  [tab_bar setBadgeValue:nil];
              }



    }
```

for use this method
in every viewController create

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;




self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  [self.appDelegate update_badgeWithViewControllerIndex:yourViewControllerIndex];
```

Comment: not working!! still badge updates only if we go on that view controller. thanks for the response

Comment: in fact i have tried the other way round also. created protocol of view controller and your method and delegate the method to AppDelegate.m , include .h file of my current view controller in AppDelegate.h declare the protocol and now xcode giving the strange error   "" Cannot find protocol declaration for .......""".

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVO to observe the change in your `upcomingcount` and update your badge value.

```
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{

        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(upcomingcount))]) {
            //SET BADGE VALUE HERE

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func setBadge(){
        let viewconrollers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers
        viewconrollers![3].tabBarItem.badgeValue = "Your String value"
        viewconrollers![3].tabBarItem.badgeColor = UIColor.green
    }


//call setBadge() method from view controller's viewdidload method.

// select your give number it the view controllers array for providing badge on the desired tab
```